# BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@c4322f2

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, logcat

```
    public class ForceOfflineReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("You are forced to be offline. Please try to login again.");
                dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCollector.finishAll(); 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        context.startActivity(intent); 
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

When I Click the button,there is no dialog appears.
And The log is:

> 08-21 10:40:05.756 13851-13851/com.project.ics.day0821rememberpassword
>   V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@c4322f2 08-21 10:40:05.757
>   13851-13851/com.project.ics.day0821rememberpassword V/BoostFramework:
>   BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@667cd43 08-21
>   10:41:06.499 13851-13851/com.project.ics.day0821rememberpassword
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: clearMetaKeyStates on inactive
>   InputConnection 08-21 10:41:07.559
>   13851-13851/com.project.ics.day0821rememberpassword I/Choreographer:
>   Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread.

source code on github:
https://github.com/gowufang/AndroidStu/tree/master/Day0821RememberPassword

Answer (score -1):

may be you have not set the name of the method which is getting executed when you press the button or you have spelled it wrong,I had this issue but later I got it.("onClick" property name of the button is not set or set wrong)

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question. Maybe it was intended as a comment?

Comment: Both question and answer are not easy to understand